# Where did Bor hide the Aether?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

After stealing the Aether from Malekith,  where did Bor hide it?

> Bury it deep. Somewhere no-one will ever find it

Comment: Bury him next to that Parallax guy ...

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly Svartalfheim, former home of The Dark Elves, The Dark World itself.

It's a barren, desolate wasteland following the first war, making it the perfect place to hide something. There's also the fact that it resides in a star system that is ravaged by Dark Matter, something The Aether is known to produce, and that when Jane Foster found The Aether, the Dark Elves on Svartalfheim woke up. The link could extend lightyears across worlds, but I think it's more likely that it's because they're on the same planet.

You can also narrow it down to Svartalfheim via some brief logic that isn't quite concrete, but it makes sense:

- Jane enters a portal to find it, so it must be one of the Nine Realms.
- It's not Asgard, Midgard or Jotunheim. The Asgard wouldn't keep it close to The Tesseract, Jane had to leave Earth to find it and Jotunheim is full of Ice Giants. Not a good plan.
- It's also probably not Alfheim, Niflheim or Muspelheim, because supposedly we haven't seen any of those worlds on-screen.
- That leaves us with either Nidavellir, Svartalfheim or Vanaheim. Two of these worlds are inhabited by Dwarves and the Vanir, so I don't think Bor would have The Aether hidden in either of them, since it could potentially be found again.

Which leaves us with Svartalfheim.

Personally, I think it's the only logical choice. But if anybody can show something that disproves anything I've said, they're welcome.

Comment: "The Asgard wouldn't keep it close to The Tesseract, Jane had to leave Earth to find it" - Technically, given the way some of the portals worked, Jane could easily have been back on Earth (or anywhere) when she found it. But also, the Tesseract was specifically brought to Earth by Odin, so the Aether could have been on Asgard and the first point would still hold (e.g. if Odin brought the Tesseract to Earth to separate them? Maybe they didn't always know that it isn't wise to keep two Infinity Stones near each other?)

Comment: After the Battle of New York, Thor brought the Tesseract back to Asgard alongside himself and Loki. I do not believe they would have kept it there if The Aether was also there, especially given that at the end of the movie they hand The Aether over to the Collector for the same reason. So I really don't think The Aether's on Asgard. As for the portals, I always thought that matter only passed _between_ realms when going through them, but maybe I'm mistaken. Either way, I wouldn't want humans potentially finding an item of great power, so I don't think it's on Midgard either.

Comment: "After the Battle of New York, Thor brought the Tesseract back to Asgard ... The Aether over to the Collector for the same reason" - I'd argue they were pretty special circumstances. Thor NEEDED the Tesseract to get back to Asgard according to the movie, and there's no saying that they had long-term plans to host the Tesseract there. The comment about "unwise to keep them together ...." also came out of The Dark World, which makes it perfectly plausible that it was the events of TDW (and Asgard being penetrated) that led them to adopt this philosophy from that point on.

Comment: But the Tesseract was left on Earth by the Asgardians anyway when they first came .... that's why Hugo Schmidt could find it in a random temple during WWII. The logic of "I wouldn't keep it on Earth because inhabited" already didn't apply to one Infinity Stone, which calls into question the logic of "Nidavellir and Vanaheim are inhabited"

Comment: Odin left the Tesseract on Earth for reasons best known to himself (maybe he just lost it, who knows?). Bor explicitly said "Somewhere no-one will ever find it". Svartlafheim would be such a place, because as Bor believed at the time, it was completely uninhabited (Bor thought Malekith was dead). Rather than pick random little holes in my theory about other worlds, it might be more worthwhile  to prove why it couldn't possibly be Svartalfheim, because that's where I think it is.

Comment: Svartalfheim >might< be one of the worlds, but it's only an answer to the question if the logic to narrow down to it holds up. It wasn't inhabited when Jane Foster found the Aether either (and Bor certainly knew the Convergence was a thing). There are even places on Earth that mean even if the world is inhabited, Men cannot survive going there (the Ocean floor is a trope). You could speculate Svartalfheim is a >possible< hiding place, and that you find it >more likely<, but it's a stretch to say "It's almost certainly Svartalfheim,". Why would anyone have to prove it couldn't >possibly< be?

Answer (score -1):

I know different people have replied different ways... one person said Svartálfheim and someone else said maybe Asgard, but I think the answer is neither... I think the Aether was stored somewhere that most likely we will never know the answer... I say this as someone who knows about Marvel Comics but more importantly as someone who knows a good deal about Norse mythology.

In *Thor: The Dark World*, Jane Foster gets sucked into a mysterious dark place where the Aether joins with her. If you think back to the events of the movie, when she disappeared to whereever it was that the Aether was, even Heimdall wasn’t able to see her. In both the MCU and Norse mythology, Heimdall is the guardian of Asgard due to his ability to see all and hear all. If Jane Foster had been pulled into Svartálfheim aka The Dark World, Heimdall would have been able to see her because Svartálfheim is one of the Nine Realms.

For that reason, I think Jane Foster was most likely pulled into some darker, more primeval world, a world that even Heimdall couldn’t see.